# nested ReorderableListView flutter dart - drago and drop lists inside list

Tags: flutter, dart, drag-and-drop, nested-lists

I've been trying `ReorderableListView` two create a list that you are able to drag and drop but also that contains items that you are also able to drag a drop. I know there is the package `drag_and_drop_lists` but don't recommend it to me. I want to manage to built something like this without the need of a third party package.

Also, it is dynamic and the issue that I am having is with the items inside the list, I just don't know which list is calling and only returns the item number that is going to replace but if I have 4 lists each one with x amount of items, how can I know which list is replacing ?

[Link to example, don't have reputation :(](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1n6qI.gif)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.